# Быстрое избавление от функции в цепочке функций

Tags: javascript

Есть цепочка функций:

```
functionA(
    functionB(
        functionC(
            functionD(
                functionE(myVariable)
            )
        )
    )
);
```

При достижении какого-то условия может понадобиться отказаться, например, от функции `functionC` в этой цепочке. Для понимания, вот один из вариантов решения:

```
let trueOrFalse = Math.random() >= 0.5;

if (trueOrFalse) {  //если true, то выполняем цепочку с functionC
    functionA(functionB(functionC(functionD(functionE(myVariable)))));
}
else { //если false, то выполняем цепочку без functionC
    functionA(functionB(functionD(functionE(myVariable))));
}
```

Вот еще вариант. Тут мы не создаем полностью изолированные цепочки, а возвращаем нужную с нужного места:

```
let trueOrFalse = Math.random() >= 0.5;

functionA(
    functionB(
        trueOrFalse ?
            functionC( //если true, то выполняем цепочку с functionC
                functionD(
                    functionE(myVariable)
                )
            )
            :
            functionD( //если false, то выполняем цепочку без functionC
                functionE(myVariable)
            )
    )
);
```

Сразу понятен минус всех этих примеров - излишнее дублирование кода. А что, если в цепочке будет гораздо больше функций? Каким образом можно сделать то же, что и в примерах выше, но без дублирования кода? Возможно решение где-то на поверхности, но у меня не получилось его разглядеть.

П.С. не хотел делить вопрос на два разных ввиду схожести, поэтому вот бонус: как без дублирования кода избавиться от метода `methodC` в цепочке при `trueOrFalse === false`, но выполнить метод при `trueOrFalse === true`?

```
let trueOrFalse = Math.random() >= 0.5;

myVariable.methodA().methodB().methodC().methodD().methodE();
```

Comment: Привет Михаил! Вдруг успеешь, приглашаю - [Новогодний конкурс 2020 года](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1061127/28748)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function execChain(funcs, param) {
  var res = param;
  for(var i = 0; i < funcs.length; i++) {
    if (funcs[i])
      res = funcs[i](res);
  }
  return res;
}

execChain([
  functionE, 
  functionD, 
  trueOrFalse? functionC : null, 
  functionB, 
  functionA], 123
);
```

Для другого вида цепочки - аналогично, только вызывать функции:

```
res = funcs[i].call(res);
```