# Новогодний конкурс 2021 года!

Tags: любой-язык, соревнование

В прошлом году такой конкурс был очень веселый! ;) Давайте проведем и в этом тоже!

#### А чего делать-то будем?

Для победы в соревновании необходимо реализовать как минимум одну анимацию из следующих:

- анимация елочки;
- анимация Деда Мороза;
- анимация снежинки и падающего снега;

Чем больше сценариев будет в вашем ответе, тем лучше. При желании, вы можете добавить дополнительные анимации на тему Нового Года. Они будут «плюсом» к обязательным анимациям.

## Всем веселья! Всем праздника!

Comment: Sorry for writing in English here, but [I removed your SmokeDetector pings](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62889756#62889756) (and removed my earlier comments here about the topic).

Answer (score 40):

**CSS.** Простая снежинка.

upd_one. Добавим немного падающего снега.

upd_two. Добавим Новогоднюю ёлку.

upd_three. Добавим Деда Мороза.

upd_four. Добавим снеговика.

upd_five. Добавим горы и луну.

upd_six. Добавим Новогодний шар с логотипом ruSO.

upd_seven. Добавим лопату и ведро.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #afd9f7;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #afd9f7, #459cf7);
}


/*горы*/

.mountains {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

.mountain_1,
.mountain_2,
.mountain_3,
.mountain_4,
.mountain_5,
.mountain_6,
.mountain_7,
.mountain_8,
.mountain_9 {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.mountain_1 {
  margin-left: -5vw;
  border-right: 400px solid transparent;
  border-left: 150px solid transparent;
}

.mountain_2 {
  margin-left: 15vw;
  border-right: 400px solid transparent;
  border-left: 400px solid transparent;
}

.mountain_3 {
  margin-left: 70vw;
  border-right: 150px solid transparent;
  border-left: 400px solid transparent;
}

.mountain_4 {
  margin-left: -15vw;
  border-right: 400px solid transparent;
  border-left: 500px solid transparent;
}

.mountain_5 {
  margin-left: 25vw;
  border-right: 350px solid transparent;
  border-left: 150px solid transparent;
}

.mountain_6 {
  margin-left: 70vw;
  border-right: 200px solid transparent;
  border-left: 200px solid transparent;
}

.mountain_7 {
  margin-left: 15vw;
  border-right: 150px solid transparent;
  border-left: 250px solid transparent;
}

.mountain_8 {
  margin-left: 50vw;
  border-right: 300px solid transparent;
  border-left: 150px solid transparent;
}

.mountain_9 {
  margin-left: 60vw;
  border-right: 300px solid transparent;
  border-left: 250px solid transparent;
}

.mountain_one {
  border-bottom: 120px solid #459cf7;
}

.mountain_two {
  border-bottom: 100px solid #50aef1;
}

.mountain_three {
  border-bottom: 55px solid #79c4f9;
}

.mount_snow {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #daedfb;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.mount_snow:before,
.mount_snow:after {
  content: "";
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #daedfb;
  position: absolute;
}

.mount_snow:before {
  left: 10%;
  height: 36px;
  transform: rotate(5deg);
  bottom: -4px;
  width: 40vw;
}

.mount_snow:after {
  right: -10%;
  height: 20px;
  bottom: 6px;
  width: 65vw;
}


/*/горы*/


/*луна*/

.moon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: cornsilk;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 20px 6px #fff;
}

.moon:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 95% 0, 95% 30%, 70% 40%, 80% 80%, 40% 70%, 10% 90%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 95% 0, 95% 30%, 70% 40%, 80% 80%, 40% 70%, 10% 90%);
}


/*/луна*/


/*снежинка*/

.snowflake_container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 170px;
  animation: 5s infinite linear animate;
  z-index: 3;
}

.snowflake {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 5px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.snowflake:before,
.snowflake:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -12px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 5px solid snow;
  border-top: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.snowflake:after {
  bottom: 0;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.snow__two {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.snow__three {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.snow__four {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

@keyframes animate {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}


/*/снежинка*/


/*падающий_снег*/

.snow {
  position: fixed;
  top: -20%;
  cursor: default;
  user-select: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  animation-duration: 10s, 3s;
  animation-name: snow_f, snow_s;
  animation-play-state: running, running;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite, infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear, ease-in-out;
  z-index: 2;
}

@keyframes snow_f {
  0% {
    top: -10%;
  }
  100% {
    top: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes snow_s {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(80px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}

.snow:nth-of-type(0) {
  left: 1%;
  animation-delay: 0s, 0s;
}

.snow:nth-of-type(1) {
  left: 10%;
  animation-delay: 1s, 1s;
}

.snow:nth-of-type(2) {
  left: 20%;
  animation-delay: 6s, .5s;
}

.snow:nth-of-type(3) {
  left: 30%;
  animation-delay: 4s, 2s;
}

.snow:nth-of-type(4) {
  left: 40%;
  animation-delay: 2s, 2s;
}

.snow:nth-of-type(5) {
  left: 50%;
  animation-delay: 8s, 3s;
}

.snow:nth-of-type(6) {
  left: 60%;
  animation-delay: 6s, 2s;
}

.snow:nth-of-type(7) {
  left: 70%;
  animation-delay: 2.5s, 1s;
}

.snow:nth-of-type(8) {
  left: 80%;
  animation-delay: 1s, 0s;
}

.snow:nth-of-type(9) {
  left: 90%;
  animation-delay: 3s, 1.5s;
}

.snow:nth-of-type(10) {
  left: 99%;
  animation-delay: 10s, 9s;
}


/*/падающий_снег*/


/*елка*/

.tree {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 40px 75px 40px;
  border-color: transparent transparent green transparent;
}

.tree:before,
.tree:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  right: -34px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 35px 60px 35px;
  border-color: transparent transparent green transparent;
}

.tree:before {
  top: -35px;
  right: -24px;
  border-width: 0 25px 45px 25px;
}

.tree__trunk {
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  right: -6px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  background: brown;
}

.star {
  position: absolute;
  top: -60px;
  left: -14px;
  cursor: default;
  user-select: none;
  color: darkred;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  animation: 3s infinite linear star;
  z-index: 1;
}

@keyframes star {
  0% {
    color: darkred;
  }
  93% {
    color: red;
  }
  95% {
    color: gold;
  }
  98% {
    color: red;
  }
  100% {
    color: darkred;
  }
}

.tree__lights__one {
  position: absolute;
  top: 44px;
  right: -26px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 40%;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px;
  transform: rotateZ(-12deg);
  z-index: 1;
}

.tree__lights__one:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  left: -2px;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  animation: blink_one 2s linear infinite;
}

.tree__lights__two {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  right: -18px;
  width: 47px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px;
  transform: rotateZ(-16deg);
  z-index: 1;
}

.tree__lights__two:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: -6px;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  animation: blink_two 1s linear infinite alternate;
}

.tree__lights__three {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  right: -12px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px;
  transform: rotateZ(-16deg);
  z-index: 1;
}

.tree__lights__three:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: -8px;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  animation: blink_three 1s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes blink_one {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 5px -1px #008bff, 24px 1px #fff, 40px 1px #ffdc00, 54px 0px #f00;
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: 5px -1px #f00, 24px 1px #008bff, 40px 1px #fff, 54px 0px #ffdc00;
  }
  75% {
    box-shadow: 5px -1px #ffdc00, 24px 1px #f00, 40px 1px #00bcff, 54px 0px #fff;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 5px -1px #fff, 24px 1px #ffdc00, 40px 1px #f00, 54px 0px #00bcff;
  }
}

@keyframes blink_two {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 5px -1px #008bff, 20px 1px #fff, 34px 1px #ffdc00, 46px 0px #f00;
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: 5px -1px #f00, 20px 1px #008bff, 34px 1px #fff, 46px 0px #ffdc00;
  }
  75% {
    box-shadow: 5px -1px #ffdc00, 20px 1px #f00, 34px 1px #00bcff, 46px 0px #fff;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 5px -1px #fff, 20px 1px #ffdc00, 34px 1px #f00, 46px 0px #00bcff;
  }
}

@keyframes blink_three {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 5px 3px #008bff, 20px 7px #f00, 34px 4px #ffdc00;
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: 5px 3px #ffdc00, 20px 7px #008bff, 34px 4px #f00;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 5px 3px #f00, 20px 7px #ffdc00, 34px 4px #008bff;
  }
}


/*/елка*/


/*дед_мороз*/

.ded_moroz_container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 10px;
}

body:hover .ded_moroz_container {
  animation: ded_moroz_container 0.6s 1;
}

@keyframes ded_moroz_container {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0turn);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(0.02turn) scale(1.1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-0.02turn) scale(1.1);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(0.02turn) scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0turn) scale(1);
  }
}

.ded_moroz {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  animation: ded_moroz___head 4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes ded_moroz___head {
  0% {
    bottom: 13px;
  }
  45% {
    bottom: 13px;
  }
  50% {
    bottom: 20px;
  }
  92% {
    bottom: 20px;
  }
  98% {
    bottom: 13px;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 13px;
  }
}

.ded_moroz_body {
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  bottom: -50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #E30E0E;
  border-radius: 100%;
  animation: ded_moroz___body 4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes ded_moroz___body {
  0% {
    bottom: -50px;
  }
  2% {
    bottom: -53px;
  }
  4% {
    bottom: -50px;
  }
  8% {
    bottom: -53px;
  }
  10% {
    bottom: -50px;
  }
  12% {
    bottom: -53px;
  }
  14% {
    bottom: -50px;
  }
  18% {
    bottom: -53px;
  }
  20% {
    bottom: -50px;
  }
  22% {
    bottom: -53px;
  }
  24% {
    bottom: -50px;
  }
  28% {
    bottom: -53px;
  }
  30% {
    bottom: -50px;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: -50px;
  }
}

.ded_moroz_body:before,
.ded_moroz_body:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 53px;
  left: 48px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

.ded_moroz_body:after {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.ded_moroz_beard {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0 50% 50% 50%;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.ded_moroz_face {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 45px;
  left: 6px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 48px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #fcd9c3;
}

.ded_moroz_eye_one,
.ded_moroz_eye_two {
  position: relative;
  height: 1px;
  width: 10px;
  border-top: 3px solid #262626;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  animation: ded_moroz___eye 4s linear infinite;
}

.ded_moroz_eye_one {
  top: 5px;
  left: 6px;
}

.ded_moroz_eye_two {
  top: 1px;
  left: 32px;
  animation: ded_moroz___eye_two 4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes ded_moroz___eye {
  30% {
    border-top: 3px solid #262626;
  }
  55% {
    border-top: 3px solid #262626;
  }
  55.1% {
    border-top: 4px solid #262626;
  }
  100% {
    border-top: 4px solid #262626;
  }
}

@keyframes ded_moroz___eye_two {
  30% {
    top: 1px;
    border-top: 3px solid #262626;
  }
  55% {
    top: 1px;
    border-top: 3px solid #262626;
  }
  55.1% {
    top: 0px;
    border-top: 4px solid #262626;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0px;
    border-top: 4px solid #262626;
  }
}

.ded_moroz_nose {
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  left: 19px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fbd1b6;
}

.ded_moroz_mouth {
  position: relative;
  top: 6px;
  left: 18px;
  height: 3px;
  width: 13px;
  border-radius: 0 0 13px 13px;
  background-color: #262626;
  opacity: 0.8;
  animation: ded_moroz___mouth 4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes ded_moroz___mouth {
  0% {
    height: 3px;
  }
  55% {
    height: 3px;
  }
  55.1% {
    height: 6px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 6px;
  }
}

.ded_moroz_cap {
  position: absolute;
  top: -45px;
  left: 2px;
  width: 54px;
  height: 60px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 100% 20% 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: monospace;
  color: darkred;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.ded_moroz_cap:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: -1px;
  width: 57px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 100% / 50%;
  transform: rotate(-2deg);
  box-shadow: inset 0 10px lightyellow;
}

.ded_moroz_cap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: lightyellow;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}


/*/дед_мороз*/


/*снеговик*/

.snowman_container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -4px;
  right: 120px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 62px;
  animation-name: snowman;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes snowman {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(6deg);
    right: 110px;
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-6deg);
    right: 130px;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(6deg);
    right: 110px;
  }
}

.snowman {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 62px;
}

.snowman_shadow {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 12px;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.9) 0%, rgba(138, 174, 188, 0) 60%, rgba(206, 223, 235, 0) 100%);
}

.snowman_body {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 29px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 0%, #dbe8fc 100%);
  box-shadow: 7px -5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}

.snowman_head {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 4px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 0%, #dbe8fc 100%);
  box-shadow: 7px -5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}

.snowman_coal {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 14px 36px 0px 0px #222, 14px 40px 0px 0px #222, 14px 44px 0px 0px #222, 10px 18px 0px 0px #222, 16px 18px 0px 0px #222;
}

.snowman_carrot {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1px;
  top: 22px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-right: 14px solid orangered;
  border-top: 2px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}

.snowman_scarf {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 3px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 40px;
  background: chocolate;
  border-radius: 70% 70% 50% 50%;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(1% 32%, 1% 21%, 98% 21%, 97% 35%, 98% 51%, 81% 35%, 95% 59%, 87% 66%, 71% 34%);
  clip-path: polygon(1% 32%, 1% 21%, 98% 21%, 97% 35%, 98% 51%, 81% 35%, 95% 59%, 87% 66%, 71% 34%);
}

.snowman_hand_l {
  position: absolute;
  left: -7px;
  top: 24px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #9b441b;
  transform: rotate(290deg);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(18% 17%, 35% 30%, 38% 0, 41% 0, 41% 30%, 71% 16%, 79% 15%, 40% 38%, 39% 100%, 35% 100%, 34% 37%, 9% 16%);
  clip-path: polygon(18% 17%, 35% 30%, 38% 0, 41% 0, 41% 30%, 71% 16%, 79% 15%, 40% 38%, 39% 100%, 35% 100%, 34% 37%, 9% 16%);
}

.snowman_hand_r {
  position: absolute;
  left: 26px;
  top: 26px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #9b441b;
  transform: rotate(65deg);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(18% 17%, 35% 30%, 38% 0, 41% 0, 41% 30%, 71% 16%, 79% 15%, 40% 38%, 39% 100%, 35% 100%, 34% 37%, 9% 16%);
  clip-path: polygon(18% 17%, 35% 30%, 38% 0, 41% 0, 41% 30%, 71% 16%, 79% 15%, 40% 38%, 39% 100%, 35% 100%, 34% 37%, 9% 16%);
}

.snowman_bucket {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 8px;
  height: 0;
  width: 10px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border-top: 14px solid chocolate;
  border-left: 2px solid transparent;
  border-right: 2px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px 50%;
  transform: rotate(185deg);
}


/*/снеговик*/


/*шар*/

.ball_container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 33px;
  left: 103px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  animation-name: ball_container;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: normal;
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes ball_container {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    left: 98px;
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
    left: 93px;
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    left: 103px;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    left: 98px;
  }
}

.ball_hidden {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.ball {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 100px 100px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8));
}

.ball:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 80%;
  left: 60%;
  width: 85%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 15%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%);
  transform: translateX(-80px) translateY(-90px) skewX(-20deg);
  filter: blur(10px);
}

.ball_snow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 2px;
  width: 97px;
  height: 99px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 68%, #f0f0f0 68%, #ebeff5 79%, #c5d3e8 100%);
  box-shadow: -7px -5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}

.ball_snow_area {
  position: relative;
  top: 63px;
  width: 87px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}

.ball_thread {
  width: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: seagreen;
  height: 100px;
  top: -100px;
  left: 50%;
}

.ball_thread:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 4px;
  left: -2px;
  height: 8px;
  width: 4px;
  border: 1px solid seagreen;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}

.ball_thread:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: -8px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  box-shadow: -7px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}

.ball_hidden .snow {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 0.5em;
}

.stackoverflow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  left: 14px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  background-image: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/ru/img/sprites.svg?v=f508971f422f);
  background-position: 0 -510px;
  background-size: 95px;
  z-index: 1;
}


/*/шар*/


/*лопата*/

.shovel {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 210px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  transform: rotate(5deg);
}

.shovel_handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 4px;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.shovel_stick {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 6px;
  width: 2px;
  height: 26px;
  background: #999;
}

.shovel_blade {
  position: absolute;
  top: 34px;
  left: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
  border-top: 2px solid #999;
  border-left: 2px solid #999;
  border-right: 2px solid #999;
  background-color: silver;
}


/*/лопата*/


/*ведро*/

.bucket {
  position: absolute;
  left: 180px;
  bottom: 8px;
}

.bucket_handle {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 12px;
  left: 3px;
  width: 6px;
  height: 8px;
  border-top: 1px solid #555;
  border-left: 1px solid #555;
  border-right: 1px solid #555;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

.bucket_handle_front {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 12px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #555;
  z-index: 1;
}

.bucket_edge {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 12px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 14px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #999;
}

.bucket_body {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 10px;
  border-bottom: 12px solid silver;
  border-left: 2px solid transparent;
  border-right: 2px solid transparent;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}


/*/ведро*/
```

```html
<!-горы->
<div class="mountains">
  <div class="mountain_one mountain_1"></div>
  <div class="mountain_one mountain_2"></div>
  <div class="mountain_one mountain_3"></div>
  <div class="mountain_two mountain_4"></div>
  <div class="mountain_two mountain_5"></div>
  <div class="mountain_two mountain_6"></div>
  <div class="mountain_three mountain_7"></div>
  <div class="mountain_three mountain_8"></div>
  <div class="mountain_three mountain_9"></div>
  <div class="mount_snow"></div>
</div>
<!-/горы->
<!-луна->
<div class="moon"></div>
<!-/луна->
<!-елка->
<div class="tree">
  <div class="tree__trunk"></div>
  <div class="tree__lights__one"></div>
  <div class="tree__lights__two"></div>
  <div class="tree__lights__three"></div>
  <div class="star">★</div>
</div>
<!-/елка->
<!-падающий_снег->
<div class="snows" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="snow">❅</div>
  <div class="snow">❆</div>
  <div class="snow">❅</div>
  <div class="snow">❄</div>
  <div class="snow">❅</div>
  <div class="snow">❆</div>
  <div class="snow">❅</div>
  <div class="snow">❄</div>
  <div class="snow">❆</div>
  <div class="snow">❅</div>
  <div class="snow">❆</div>
</div>
<!-/падающий_снег->
<!-снежинка->
<div class="snowflake_container">
  <div class="snowflake snow__one"></div>
  <div class="snowflake snow__two"></div>
  <div class="snowflake snow__three"></div>
  <div class="snowflake snow__four"></div>
</div>
<!-/снежинка->
<!-дед_мороз->
<div class="ded_moroz_container">
  <div class="ded_moroz_body"></div>
  <div class="ded_moroz">
    <div class="ded_moroz_beard"></div>
    <div class="ded_moroz_face">
      <div class="ded_moroz_eye_one"></div>
      <div class="ded_moroz_eye_two"></div>
      <div class="ded_moroz_nose"></div>
      <div class="ded_moroz_mouth"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ded_moroz_cap">дед</div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-/дед_мороз->
<!-снеговик->
<div class="snowman_container">
  <div class="snowman">
    <div class="snowman_shadow"></div>
    <div class="snowman_body"></div>
    <div class="snowman_head"></div>
    <div class="snowman_coal"></div>
    <div class="snowman_carrot"></div>
    <div class="snowman_hand_l"></div>
    <div class="snowman_hand_r"></div>
    <div class="snowman_scarf"></div>
    <div class="snowman_bucket"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-/снеговик->
<!-шар->
<div class="ball_container">
  <div class="ball_hidden">
    <div class="stackoverflow"></div>
    <div class="snows" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="snow">❅</div>
      <div class="snow">❆</div>
      <div class="snow">❅</div>
      <div class="snow">❄</div>
      <div class="snow">❅</div>
      <div class="snow">❆</div>
      <div class="snow">❅</div>
      <div class="snow">❄</div>
      <div class="snow">❆</div>
      <div class="snow">❅</div>
      <div class="snow">❆</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ball">
  </div>
  <div class="ball_snow">
    <div class="ball_snow_area"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="ball_thread"></div>
</div>
<!-/шар->
<!-лопата->
<div class="shovel">
  <div class="shovel_handle"></div>
  <div class="shovel_stick"></div>
  <div class="shovel_blade"></div>
</div>
<!-/лопата->
<!-ведро->
<div class="bucket">
  <div class="bucket_handle"></div>
  <div class="bucket_handle_front"></div>
  <div class="bucket_edge"></div>
  <div class="bucket_body"></div>
</div>
<!-/ведро->
```

Comment: Где-то увидишь такое, и не подумаешь, что сделано на CSS, крайне круто))

Comment: вауу круто, неужели на html css только так можно

Answer (score 32):

**С новым годом! :))**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Немного консольной графики на C++. Подкрутите константные переменные `HEIGHT` и `WIDTH` если картинка не умещается.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <deque>
#include <algorithm>

#include <random>


constexpr size_t HEIGHT = 40;
constexpr size_t WIDTH = 160;
constexpr int64_t SLEEP_PER_FRAME = 10;
constexpr size_t SNOWFLAKE_CHANCE = 3;

std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 generator(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<> distribution(1, 100);

std::string make_snow_row()
{
  std::string row(WIDTH, ' ');

  for (auto& symb : row) {
    if (distribution(generator) < SNOWFLAKE_CHANCE) {
      symb = '*';
    }
  }

  return row;
}

void init_snow(std::vector<std::string>& snow)
{
  for (auto& row : snow) {
    row = make_snow_row();
  }
}

void init_tree(std::deque<std::string>& tree)
{
  std::string half_empty_string = std::string(WIDTH / 2 - 10, ' ');

  for (auto& row : tree) {
    row = half_empty_string + row + half_empty_string;
  }

  size_t empty_height = HEIGHT - tree.size();
  std::string empty_string = std::string(WIDTH, ' ');
  for (size_t i = 0; i < empty_height; ++i) {
    tree.push_front(empty_string);
  }
}

void make_frame(std::vector<std::string>& frame,
  const std::vector<std::string>& snow, const std::deque<std::string>& tree)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < HEIGHT; ++i) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < WIDTH; ++j) {
      if (snow[i][j] == '*') {
        frame[i][j] = '*';
      }
      else if (tree[i][j] != ' ') {
        frame[i][j] = tree[i][j];
      }
      else {
        frame[i][j] = ' ';
      }
    }
  }
}

void draw_frame(const std::vector<std::string>& frame)
{
  for (const auto& row : frame) {
    std::cout << row << '\n';
  }
  std::cout << std::setw(WIDTH + 1) << std::setfill('*') << '\n';
}

void move_snow(std::vector<std::string>& snow)
{
  auto rbegin = snow.rbegin();
  auto prerend = std::prev(snow.rend());
  for (auto it = rbegin; it != prerend; ++it) {
    *it = std::move(*std::next(it));
  }
  snow[0] = make_snow_row();
}

void sleep(const int64_t ms)
{
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(ms));
}

void clear_console()
{
  system("cls");
}


int main()
{
  std::deque<std::string> tree = {
        "               /\\               ",
        "              / \\\\             ",
        "             /   \\\\            ",
        "            /   o \\\\           ",
        "           /_ $   _\\\\          ",
        "            /     \\\\           ",
        "           /    $  \\\\          ",
        "          / $     o \\\\         ",
        "         /_         _\\\\        ",
        "          /    o    \\\\         ",
        "         /  o        \\\\        ",
        "        /o       o    \\\\       ",
        "       /_     $       _\\\\      ",
        "        /       o     \\\\       ",
        "       /      o        \\\\      ",
        "      /   $        o    \\\\     ",
        "     /_        $      o _\\\\    ",
        "      /     o     o     \\\\     ",
        "     /    o     $        \\\\    ",
        "    / $        o     o    \\\\   ",
        "   /_______________________\\\\  ",
        "             |    |              ",
        "             |    |              "
  };
  init_tree(tree);

  std::vector<std::string> snow(HEIGHT);
  init_snow(snow);

  std::vector<std::string> frame(HEIGHT, std::string(WIDTH, ' '));
  while (true) {
    make_frame(frame, snow, tree);
    draw_frame(frame);
    move_snow(snow);

    sleep(SLEEP_PER_FRAME);
    clear_console();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Вдохновился следующей реализацией на языке Си https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1064253/328042

Comment: Класс! С++ тоже не чуждо прекрасное. ;)

Comment: ascii art называется. https://coub.com/view/all5f

Comment: Как-то мрачновато... Впрочем, какой год, такая и ёлка.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov хаха, надо будет поиграть с цветным выводом в консоль

Answer (score 32):

**C Новым Годом!!!**

Цветная консоль на С++(256 цветов)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>


class Screen {
private:
    int height = 30;
    int width = 100;
    std::vector<uint32_t> chars;
    std::vector<uint32_t> backgroundScreen;

public:
    Screen(int width, int height) : chars(height * width, (int)((1 << 8) | ' ') ) {}
    int getWidth() { return width; }
    int getHeight() { return height; }

    void show() {
        for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
            for(int j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
                // unpack char
                int backColor = (chars[i * width + j] >> 8) & 0xff;
                int foreColor = (chars[i * width + j] >> 16) & 0xff;
                int effect = (chars[i * width + j] >> 24) & 0xff;
                char c = chars[i * width + j] & 0xff;

                std::cout << "\x1b[38:5:" << foreColor << "m";
                std::cout << "\x1b[48:5:"<< backColor << "m";
                std::cout << "\x1b["<< effect << "m" << c;
                std::cout << "\x1b[m" << "\x1b[m" << "\x1b[m";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void setCharAtXY(int x, int y, char value, uint8_t backColor = 16, uint8_t foreColor = 0, uint8_t effect = 1) {
        chars[x + y * width] = value | (backColor << 8) | (foreColor << 16) | (effect << 24);
    }

    void setCharAtXY(int x, int y, uint32_t packedChar) {
        chars[x + y * width] = packedChar;
    }

    uint32_t getCharAtXY(int x, int y) {
        return chars[x + y * width];
    }

    void clear() {

        if (backgroundScreen.size()) {
            chars = backgroundScreen;
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
                for(int j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
                    setCharAtXY(j, i, 0x01006920U);
                }
            }
        }

        std::cout << "\x1b[2J\x1b[H";
    }

    void save() {
        backgroundScreen = chars;
    }

};

struct IScreenable {
    virtual void draw(Screen& screen) = 0;
};

class Tree : public IScreenable {
private:
    int x;
    int y;
    int height;

public:
    Tree (int x, int y, int height) : x(x), y(y), height(height) {}

    void setX(int x) { this->x = x; }
    void setY(int y) { this->y = y; }

    void draw(Screen& screen) override {
        int stemWidth = 5;
        int stemHeight = 4;

        std::srand(std::time(nullptr));

        // needles
        int xx = x;
        int i = 0;
        for ( ; i < height - stemHeight; ++i, --xx) {
            for(int j = 0; j < i * 2 + 1; ++j) {
                screen.setCharAtXY(xx + j, y + i, '*', 2);
            }
            int k = std::rand() % (i * 2 + 1);
            screen.setCharAtXY(xx + k, y + i, 0x05c4026fU);
        }
        // stem
        for (xx = x; i < height; ++i) {
            for(int j = 0; j < stemWidth; ++j) {
                screen.setCharAtXY(xx - stemWidth / 2 + j, y + i, '|', 3);
            }
        }

    }
};

class Ground : public IScreenable {
private:
    int height = 5;
public:
    void draw(Screen& screen) override {
        int sHeight = screen.getHeight();
        int sWidth = screen.getWidth();
        for (int i = sHeight - height; i < sHeight; ++i) {
            for(int j = 0; j < sWidth; ++j) {
                screen.setCharAtXY(j, i, ' ', 15);
            }
        }
    }
};

class BigText : public IScreenable {
private:
    int x = 11;
    int y = 3;
    int color = 15;
public:
    void draw(Screen& screen) override {
        const int width = 15;
        int points[][width] = {
            {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, 
            {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0},
            {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0},
            {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
            {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1},
        };

        int height = (int)(sizeof(points) / sizeof(points[0]));

        for (int i = 0; i < height ; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
                if (points[i][j]) {
                    screen.setCharAtXY(x + j, y + i, ' ', color);
                }
            }
        }
    }

};

class DedMoroz : public IScreenable {
private:
    int x;
    int y;
    bool isSmiling = false;

public:
    DedMoroz(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
    void setX(int x) { this->x = x; }
    void setY(int y) { this->y = y; }
    int getX() { return x; }
    int getY() { return y; }
    void goLeft() { --x; }
    void goRight() { ++x; (x & 1) ? --y : ++y;}
    void smile() {
        isSmiling = true;
    }

    void draw(Screen& screen) override {
        const int width = 13;
        uint32_t points[][width] = {
            {0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x0106a020, 0x0106a020, 0x0106a020, 0x00000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,}, 
            {0x00000000, 0x0106a020, 0x0106a020, 0x0106a020, 0x0106a020, 0x0106a020, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,}, 
            {0x00000000, 0x01060f20, 0x01060f20, 0x01060f20, 0x01060f20, 0x01060f20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,}, 
            {0x0106df28, 0x0106df20, 0x0100df4f, 0x0106df20, 0x0100df4f, 0x0106df20, 0x0106df29, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,}, 
            {0x00000000, 0x0106df20, 0x0106df20, 0x0106df22, 0x0106df20, 0x0106df20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,}, 
            {0x00000000, 0x0106df20, 0x0106df20, 0x0106df7e, 0x0106df20, 0x0106df20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,}, 
            {0x00000000, 0x01060f20, 0x01060f20, 0x01060f20, 0x01060f20, 0x01060f20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,}, 
            {0x00000000, 0x0106a020, 0x0106a020, 0x01060f20, 0x0106a020, 0x0106a020, 0x0106a020, 0x0106df20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,}, 
            {0x00000000, 0x0106a020, 0x0106a020, 0x01060f20, 0x0106a020, 0x0106a020, 0x00000000, 0x0106a020, 0x0106a020, 0x0106a020, 0x0106a020, 0x0106a020, 0, }, 
            {0x00000000, 0x0106a020, 0x0106a020, 0x01060f20, 0x0106a020, 0x0106a020, 0x00000000, 0x0106a020, 0x0106a020, 0x0106a020, 0x0106a020, 0x0106a020, 0, }, 
            {0x00000000, 0x01060f20, 0x01060f20, 0x01060f20, 0x01060f20, 0x01060f20, 0x00000000, 0x0106a020, 0x0106a020, 0x0106a020, 0x0106a020, 0x0106a020, 0, }, 
            {0x00000000, 0x01000020, 0x01000020, 0x00000000, 0x01000020, 0x01000020, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0, }, 

        };

        int height = (int)(sizeof(points) / sizeof(points[0]));

        for (int i = 0; i < height ; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
                if (points[i][j]) {
                    screen.setCharAtXY(x + j, y + i, points[i][j]);
                }

            }
        }

        if (isSmiling) {
            uint32_t points2[][5] = {
                {0x0, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x0}, 
                {0x0, 0x0106df5c, 0x0106df5f, 0x0106df2f, 0x0}, 
            };
            int xx = x + 1;
            int yy = y + 4;
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {
                    if (points2[i][j]) {
                        screen.setCharAtXY(xx + j, yy + i, points2[i][j]);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
};

class SnowFall: public IScreenable {
private:
    int y;
    int x;
    int snowInRow = 3;
    const uint32_t packedSnowFlake = 0x010f002a;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> points;

    void step() {
        if (++y >= 30) y = 0;
        if (++x >= 100) x = 0;
    }

public:
    SnowFall() {
        y = 0;
        x = 0;
        int height = 14; 
        int sWidth = 100;
        std::srand(std::time(nullptr));
        for(int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
            std::vector<int> a;
            for(int j = 0; j < snowInRow; ++j) {
                a.push_back(std::rand() % sWidth);  
            }
            points.push_back(a);
        }
    }

    void setY(int y) { this->y = y; }
    int getY() { return y; }

    void draw(Screen& screen) override {
        int height = points.size();

        int sHeight = screen.getHeight();
        int sWidth = screen.getWidth();

        for (int i = 0; i < height ; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < snowInRow; ++j) {
                int yy = y + i * 2;
                int xx = x + points[i][j];
                if (yy >= sHeight) yy -= sHeight;
                if (xx >= sWidth) xx -= sWidth;

                uint32_t c = screen.getCharAtXY(xx, yy);
                c &= 0x0000ff00; // current background
                c |= packedSnowFlake; // change background for a snowflake

                screen.setCharAtXY(xx, yy, c);
            }
        }

        step();
    }
};

class Window: public IScreenable {
private:
    int x = 60;
    int y = 15;
    int width = 35;
    int height = 7;
    int color = 195;
public:
    void draw(Screen& screen) override {

        // vertical borders
        for (int i = 0; i < height ; ++i) {
            screen.setCharAtXY(x, y + i, ' ', color);
            screen.setCharAtXY(x + width - 1, y + i, ' ', color);
        }

        // horizontal borders
        for (int i = 1; i < width - 1; ++i) {
            screen.setCharAtXY(x + i, y, ' ', color);
            screen.setCharAtXY(x + i, y + height - 1, ' ', color);
        }

        const std::string texts[] = {
            "       HO-HO-HO, HO-HO-HO      ",
            "       MERRY CHRISTMAS !!!     ",
            "       HAPPY NEW YEAR !!!      ",
        };

        int xx = x + 2;
        int yy = y + 2;
        int size = sizeof(texts) / sizeof(texts[0]);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < (int)texts[i].size(); ++j) {
                screen.setCharAtXY(xx + j, yy + i, texts[i][j], color);
            }
        }

    }

};

int main() {
    Screen screen(100, 30);
    std::vector<IScreenable*> objects;

    screen.clear();
    // static objects for background can be saved
    Ground ground; ground.draw(screen);
    Tree tree(50, 7, 20); tree.draw(screen);
    screen.save();

    DedMoroz santa(0, 16); objects.push_back(&santa);
    SnowFall snow; objects.push_back(&snow);
    BigText text; 
    Window window; 

    bool isPlaying = true;  

    while(isPlaying) {
        screen.clear();
        santa.goRight(); // go to the tree
        if (santa.getX() == 50) {
            isPlaying = false;
            santa.smile();
            objects.push_back(&text);
            objects.push_back(&window);
        }

        for (IScreenable* const obj : objects) {
            obj->draw(screen);
        }

        screen.show();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(700));
    }

}
```

[github](https://github.com/tigertv/stackoverflow-answers/tree/master/ru-new-year-tree-1225740)

Answer (score 32):

В этом году минималистично, всех с праздником!

```js
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
requestAnimationFrame(function draw(t) {
    c.width = innerWidth;
    c.height = innerHeight;
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    for (let i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        const a = t / 1e3 + i/3,
              d = Math.sin(a)*i/2e3 + 1,
              x = c.width/2 + Math.cos(a)*i/3/d,
              y = c.height/2 + i/d;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y - 100, 2/d, 0, 7);
        ctx.fill();
    }  
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: black
}
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```

Comment: Это прекрасно - уже минуту оторваться не могу)

Comment: @Sevastopol' спасибо) приглашаю посетить мой канал в телеге https://t.me/mathimages

Answer (score 28):

Очень тяжелый код. Для просмотра требуется мощная видеокарта. Всех с Новым годом!

```css
.tree {color:green;font-size:8em;text-shadow:-10px 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);}
```

```html
<span class="tree"></span>
```

Comment: Шутник! ;DDDDDD

Comment: блин у меня не запускается :(. если вы его немного оптимизируете буду очень благодарен

Comment: @Danis, оптимизировал 

Comment: запустилась урааааааааааа!!!

Comment: у меня не запустилась, наверное видеокарта слабая. Дед Мороз отправь мне пожалуйста новую видеокарту!

Comment: RTX потянул :)))

Comment: можно ещё немного оптимизировать, надо между `tree` и `{` убрать пробел

Comment: Это не анимация.

Comment: @andreymal, а вы потыкайте в ёлочку)

Comment: @Sevastopol' потыкал, ничего не произошло. Похоже, пора выкидывать мою GTX 1050 Ti и копить на RTX 3090 :(

Comment: @andreymal, http://gamebomb.ru/gbnews/34628

Comment: @TigerTV.ru, разработчики же прямо в названии написали, что запускать игру нужно в 2077 году =)

Comment: @vp_arth, прогорят акционеры разработчиков, это ж надо так долгосрочно закладываться, чтобы в 2077 прибыль получать.

Answer (score 25):

Друзья! Уже совсем скоро закончится этот непростой год. Уходящий 2020 год стал для многих настоящим испытанием, и не удивительно, что люди мечтают о скорейшем его завершении. Будем надеяться и верить, что в Новом 2021 году жить станет лучше, легче и веселее.

Да услышит нас Дед Мороз!

```js
const second = 1000,
  minute = second * 60,
  hour = minute * 60,
  day = hour * 24,
  nextYear = new Date().getFullYear() + 1;

let countDown = new Date(`Jan 1, ${nextYear} 00:00:00`).getTime(),
  x = setInterval(function() {

    let now = new Date().getTime(),
      distance = countDown - now;

    document.getElementById('days').innerHTML = Math.floor(distance / (day)),
      document.getElementById('hours').innerHTML = Math.floor((distance % (day)) / (hour)),
      document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = Math.floor((distance % (hour)) / (minute)),
      document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = Math.floor((distance % (minute)) / second);
  }, second)
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(https://jooinn.com/images/christmas-background-19.jpg) bottom center;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

li span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2.8rem;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border-radius: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  line-height: 3rem;
  margin: 20px auto 10px auto;
  border: 1px solid gold;
  color: brown;
}

#days {
  width: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span id="days"></span>дней</li>
  <li><span id="hours"></span>часов</li>
  <li><span id="minutes"></span>минут</li>
  <li><span id="seconds"></span>секунд</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Красиво! ;)....

Comment: ошибочка, -1 день -2 часа 1 января.

Comment: Осталось 363 дня? Ну ок, подождём :D

Answer (score 24):

Запустите SQL*Plus в xterm или в командном окне Windows 10, и выполните следующий запрос. Получите ёлочку со случайно разбросанными огоньками и, конечно же, в насыщенном цвете.

С Новым Годом всех!

```
set lines 350 pagesize 0
clear screen

select 
    replace(
        replace(
            replace(r,
                'X', chr(27)||'[42m'||chr(27)||'[1;'||to_char(32)||'m'||'X'||chr(27)||'[0m'),
            'T',chr(27)||'[43m'||chr(27)||'[1;'||to_char(33)||'m'||'T'||chr(27)||'[0m'),
        '@',chr(27)||'[33m'||chr(27)||'[1;'||to_char(31)||'m'||'@'||chr(27)||'[0m')
from ( 
    select lpad(' ',20-e-i)|| 
        case when dbms_random.value < 0.3 then substr(s,1,e*2-3+i*2) 
        else substr(substr(s,1,dbms_random.value(1,e*2-3+i*2-1))||'@'||s,1,e*2-3+i*2) end r
    from ( 
        select rpad('X',40,'X') s,rpad('T',40,'T') t from dual ), ( 
            select level i, level+2 hop from dual connect by level<= 4), lateral ( 
                select level e from dual connect by level<=hop) 
                union all 
                select lpad(' ',17)||substr(t,1,3)
        from ( 
            select rpad('X',40,'X') s, rpad('T',40,'T') t from dual ) connect by level<=5)
/
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65434427) от участника [@Connor McDonald](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7367293/connor-mcdonald)</sub>

Comment: В psql не работает.

Comment: А что такое psql?

Comment: Утилита postgresql. ;)

Comment: Нет, нужен  SQL*Plus с соединеннием к Oracle.

Answer (score 24):

У меня чуть попроще - даже попросил помощи у [конкурентов](https://qna.habr.com/q/913635?e=10571871#answer_item_1840935) stackoverflow - в общем звёздочка с эффектом при наведении ...

```js
const svg = document.getElementById('svg');
const {
  width,
  height
} = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
const step = 10;
const distance = 55;

for (let x = 0; x < width; x += step) {
  for (let y = 0; y < height; y += step) {
    const circle = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');

    circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cx', x);
    circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cy', y);
    circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'r', 4);

    svg.appendChild(circle);
  }
}

const circles = svg.querySelectorAll('circle');

svg.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  if (e.target !== this) {
    return;
  }

  const {
    offsetX: x,
    offsetY: y
  } = e;

  circles.forEach(function(n) {
    const dx = n.getAttribute('cx') - x;
    const dy = n.getAttribute('cy') - y;
    const d = Math.sqrt(dx ** 2 + dy ** 2);

    if (d <= distance) {
      const tx = (distance - d) * Math.sign(dx);
      const ty = (distance - d) * Math.sign(dy);
      n.style.transform = `translate(${tx}px, ${ty}px)`;
    } else {
      n.style.transform = '';
    }
  });
});

svg.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  circles.forEach(n => n.style.transform = '');
});
```

```css
circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  transition: transform 0.34s linear;
}

.red {
  fill: red;
}

#svg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
<defs>
  <clipPath id="clip" clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse" style="transform: scale(4)">

<path d="M81.059,35.09l-19.787-2.873c-1.125-0.164-2.102-0.873-2.605-1.893l-8.85-17.932c-1.27-2.57-4.936-2.57-6.207,0   l-8.848,17.932c-0.504,1.02-1.479,1.729-2.605,1.893L12.369,35.09c-2.838,0.416-3.971,3.904-1.918,5.904L24.77,54.951   c0.816,0.797,1.188,1.939,0.996,3.059l-3.381,19.711c-0.484,2.826,2.48,4.984,5.021,3.646l17.697-9.305   c1.008-0.529,2.213-0.529,3.221,0l17.697,9.305c2.539,1.338,5.506-0.82,5.021-3.646L67.662,58.01   c-0.191-1.119,0.182-2.262,0.996-3.059l14.316-13.957C85.029,38.994,83.896,35.506,81.059,35.09z M76.816,42.99L65.578,53.951   c-0.816,0.791-1.189,1.936-0.994,3.061l2.652,15.471c0.484,2.826-2.48,4.977-5.02,3.646l-13.893-7.303   c-1.008-0.529-2.213-0.529-3.221,0l-13.891,7.303c-2.539,1.33-5.506-0.82-5.02-3.646l2.654-15.471   c0.191-1.125-0.182-2.27-0.996-3.061L16.611,42.99c-2.055-1.996-0.918-5.484,1.92-5.898l15.531-2.256   c1.125-0.16,2.1-0.871,2.604-1.895l6.943-14.068c1.271-2.572,4.938-2.572,6.207,0l6.945,14.068   c0.504,1.023,1.479,1.734,2.605,1.895l15.531,2.256C77.736,37.506,78.869,40.994,76.816,42.99z"/><path d="M67.297,40.43L56.76,38.898c-1.053-0.156-1.963-0.814-2.434-1.77l-4.713-9.549c-1.186-2.402-4.613-2.402-5.799,0   l-4.711,9.549c-0.473,0.955-1.383,1.613-2.436,1.77L26.133,40.43c-2.652,0.383-3.713,3.645-1.795,5.514l7.627,7.432   c0.762,0.742,1.107,1.816,0.928,2.865l-1.799,10.49c-0.455,2.645,2.318,4.658,4.689,3.412l9.426-4.957   c0.941-0.496,2.066-0.496,3.01,0l9.426,4.957c2.371,1.246,5.145-0.768,4.689-3.412l-1.799-10.49   c-0.18-1.049,0.166-2.123,0.93-2.865l7.623-7.432C71.008,44.074,69.951,40.813,67.297,40.43z"/>

  </defs>
</svg>

<svg id="svg" width="500" height="500" clip-path="url(#clip)"></svg>
```

Answer (score 21):

### Всех с прошедшим Новым годом!

```css
div {
  font-size: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  background: url(https://i.gifer.com/4V0Y.gif) #1f1e1e;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 190px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 20):

JavaScript + Canvas (довольно ресурсоёмкая "ёлочка"):

```js
function pythagoras_tree()
{
function get_next_squares(square, coefs)
{
    function coefs_to_triangle_len(coefs, len_c)
    {
        let {coef_a, coef_b} = coefs;
        
        let len = {};
        len.a = len_c * coef_a / Math.sqrt(coef_a * coef_a + coef_b * coef_b);
        len.b = len.a * coef_b / coef_a;
        len.c = len_c;
        return len;
    }
    
    function get_C_point(A, B, G, tr_len)
    {
        function get_opposite_point(A, B, G, C1, C2)
        {
            let coef_a = A.y - B.y;
            let coef_b = B.x - A.x;
            let coef_d = A.x * B.y - B.x * A.y;
        
            let f0 = coef_a * G.x + coef_b * G.y + coef_d;
            let f1 = coef_a * C1.x + coef_b * C1.y + coef_d;
        
            if (f0 * f1 < 0)
                return C1;
            return C2;
        }
        
        let p0 = A.x * A.x + A.y * A.y - tr_len.b * tr_len.b;
        let p1 = p0 + tr_len.a * tr_len.a - (B.x * B.x + B.y * B.y);
        let px = 2 * (A.x - B.x);
        let py = 2 * (A.y - B.y);
        
        let C1 = {}, C2 = {};
        if (Math.abs(px) > Math.abs(py))
        {
            let t1 = p1 / px, t2 = py / px;
            let w1 = 1 + t2 * t2;
            let w2 = 2 * (A.x * t2 - t1 * t2 - A.y);
            let w3 = p0 + t1 * t1 - 2 * A.x * t1;
            let sqrt_d = Math.sqrt(w2 * w2 - 4 * w1 * w3);
            C1.y = (-w2 + sqrt_d) / (2 * w1)
            C1.x = t1 - t2 * C1.y;
            C2.y = (-w2 - sqrt_d) / (2 * w1)
            C2.x = t1 - t2 * C2.y;
        }
        else
        {
            let t1 = p1 / py, t2 = px / py;
            let w1 = 1 + t2 * t2;
            let w2 = 2 * (A.y * t2 - t1 * t2 - A.x);
            let w3 = p0 + t1 * t1 - 2 * A.y * t1;
            let sqrt_d = Math.sqrt(w2 * w2 - 4 * w1 * w3);
            C1.x = (-w2 + sqrt_d) / (2 * w1);
            C1.y = t1 - t2 * C1.x;
            C2.x = (-w2 - sqrt_d) / (2 * w1);
            C2.y = t1 - t2 * C2.x;
        }
        return get_opposite_point(A, B, G, C1, C2);
    }
    
    function rot(begin, end, dir)
    {
        let x = end.x - begin.x;
        let y = end.y - begin.y;
        [x, y] = [dir * y, -1 * dir * x];
        x += begin.x;
        y += begin.y;
        return {x, y};
    }
    
    let tr_len = coefs_to_triangle_len(coefs, square.len);
    let C = get_C_point(square.A, square.B, square.G1, tr_len);
    
    const clock = 1, aclock = -1;
    let left_square = {
        A: rot(square.A, C, aclock), B: rot(C, square.A, clock),
        G1: square.A, G2: C,
        len: tr_len.b,
    };
    let right_square = {
        A: rot(C, square.B, aclock), B: rot(square.B, C, clock),
        G1: C, G2: square.B,
        len: tr_len.a,
    };
    return [left_square, right_square];
}

function draw_square(context, square)
{
    const canvas_width = context.canvas.width;
    const canvas_height = context.canvas.height;
    
    function is_valid_point(point)
    {
        return ( 0 <= point.x && point.x <= canvas_width &&
                 0 <= point.y && point.y <= canvas_height );
    }
    
    let {A, B, G1, G2} = square;
    if (is_valid_point(A) && is_valid_point(B) &&
        is_valid_point(G1) && is_valid_point(G2))
    {
        context.moveTo(A.x, canvas_height - A.y);
        context.lineTo(G1.x, canvas_height - G1.y);
        context.moveTo(B.x, canvas_height - B.y);
        context.lineTo(G2.x, canvas_height - G2.y);
    }
}

function create_first_square(G1, len)
{
    let first_square = {};
    first_square.A  = {x: G1.x,       y: G1.y + len};
    first_square.B  = {x: G1.x + len, y: G1.y + len};
    first_square.G1 = G1;
    first_square.G2 = {x: G1.x + len, y: G1.y      };
    first_square.len = len;
    return first_square;
}

function draw_tree(square, param, rec_depth = 0)
{
    if (rec_depth > param.max_rec_depth || square.len < param.min_square_len)
        return;
    
    draw_square(param.context, square);
    let left_right_squares = get_next_squares(square, param.coefs[rec_depth]);
    for (let next_square of left_right_squares)
        draw_tree(next_square, param, rec_depth + 1);
}

function get_param(base_param)
{
    let param = {};
    Object.setPrototypeOf(param, base_param);
    
    let coefs_arr = [];
    
    for (let i = 0; i <= param.max_rec_depth; ++i)
    {
        let coefs = {};
        if (i % 2 === 0)
        {
            coefs.coef_a = param.coefs.coef_a;
            coefs.coef_b = param.coefs.coef_b;
        }
        else
        {
            coefs.coef_a = param.coefs.coef_b;
            coefs.coef_b = param.coefs.coef_a;
        }
        coefs_arr.push(coefs);
    }
    param.coefs = coefs_arr;
    
    return param;
}

function tree_main()
{
    let context = document.getElementById("id_canvas").getContext("2d");
    context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0)"
    context.fillRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
    context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)"
    context.strokeStyle = "rgb(50, 250, 50)";
    
    let time_old = Date.now();
    let dir_current = "left_up";
    let step_current = 0;
    
    let tick = function()
    {
        const coefs_min = 1;
        const coefs_max = 1.75;
        const step_max = 1000;
        
        let coef_1 = 1;
        let coef_2 = coefs_min + (coefs_max - coefs_min) * (step_current / step_max);
        let coef_a, coef_b;
        
        switch (dir_current)
        {
            case "left_up":
                coef_a = coef_1;
                coef_b = coef_2;
                ++step_current;
                if (step_current > step_max)
                {
                    step_current = step_max;
                    dir_current = "left_down";
                }
                break;
            case "left_down":
                coef_a = coef_1;
                coef_b = coef_2;
                --step_current;
                if (step_current < 0)
                {
                    step_current = 0;
                    dir_current = "right_up";
                }
                break;
            case "right_up":
                coef_a = coef_2;
                coef_b = coef_1;
                ++step_current;
                if (step_current > step_max)
                {
                    step_current = step_max;
                    dir_current = "right_down";
                }
                break;
            case "right_down":
                coef_a = coef_2;
                coef_b = coef_1;
                --step_current;
                if (step_current < 0)
                {
                    step_current = 0;
                    dir_current = "left_up";
                }
                break;
        }
        
        let base_param = {
            context: context,
            min_square_len: 2,
            max_rec_depth: 18,
            coefs: {coef_a: coef_a, coef_b: coef_b},
        };
        let param = get_param(base_param);
        
        const base_square_len_min = 5;
        const base_square_len_max = 70;
        let base_square_len = base_square_len_min + 
            (base_square_len_max - base_square_len_min) * (step_current / step_max);
        let G1 = {x: context.canvas.width * 0.5 - base_square_len * 0.5, y: 1};
        let square = create_first_square(G1, base_square_len);
        
        context.fillRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
        context.beginPath();
        context.lineWidth = 1.0 + 2.0 * (step_current / step_max);
        draw_tree(square, param);
        context.stroke();
        
        const time_dif_base = 50;
        const time_dif_min = 10;
        let time_current = Date.now();
        let time_dif = time_current - time_old;
        time_old = time_current;
        
        let timeout = Math.min(Math.max(time_dif_base - time_dif, time_dif_min), time_dif_base);
        setTimeout(tick, timeout);
    }
    
    tick();
}

tree_main();
}

pythagoras_tree();
```

```css
canvas {border: 1px solid black}
```

```html
<canvas id = "id_canvas" height = "500" width = "500"></canvas>
```

Comment: почти фрактал кукумбер =) https://t.me/mathimages/43

Answer (score 19):

Ну, я был бы не я, если бы не поучаствовал ;)

```
print("      ⭐      ")
print("        ")
print("    ")
print("")
print("           ")
```

PS Времени, к сожалению, нет на что-то крутое и большое, но ёлочку подарить могу)

### С НАСТУПАЮЩИМ ВСЕХ!!!!!

Comment: Если это python, то "из коробки" не работает

Comment: В python3 заработал

Comment: Это не анимация.

Answer (score 19):

Сделал новогоднюю ёлочку на С++ со светящимися гирляндами! Новогоднего настроения вам[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#define miliseconds
using namespace std;

constexpr int delay = 2000 miliseconds;

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    SetConsoleTitleW(L"Праздник  ");



wstring x_mas = L"                                 ♣                                    \n" 
    L"                               **♥**                                 \n "
    L"                             **/////*,                              \n  "
    L"                           *//((♫((//*                             \n   "
    L"                          /☻(((###(((☻/                            \n   "
    L"                        ,//(☻######☻(//*                          \n   "
    L"                       *//(((☻###☻####((//*                         \n   "
    L"                     **//((((((☻(((((((//(**                       \n   "
    L"                   /**///////☻#%☻#//////**##((                     \n   "
    L"                 *****##%%%☻%%%%%%☻%///**%#####(                   \n    "
    L"               ((######%☻%%%%%%%%%%%%☻%%%%%%####((                 \n    "
    L"              ((##♫###☻#################☻#######(((                 \n   "
    L"              ((###☻####(#########♫########☻###((((                 \n   "
    L"              ▼ *☻//((######################((☻//*▼                \n    "
    L"             (**//(☻(########################((//☻*                 \n   "
    L"           ((####///(☻(((((((##############(((/☻#☼##((              \n   "
    L"       %((######%%%*///#☻////%(((((((((((((((#☻//%###☼((            \n  "
    L"        ▼ ((#####%%%%%%%%%☻%%%%%%%%#//////☻%%(((%%%%%%%%#####(((           \n "
    L"        ((((#&######%%%%%%%%☻%%%%%%%%%%%%☻%%%%%%%%%%%%########(((            \n"
    L"        *((((((#♥%############☻#%%%%%%☻%%%%%%%%#♫#####%#%//%((( ▼           \n "
    L"          ▼   *//(#(#############☻###☻##############(((###((//*              \n "
    L"           *//((##################☻(((((#♫%##((((#########(((/**            \n "
    L"         *//(((################☻#####☻####################(((/##**#         \n "
    L"      (***(/(((#############☻###########☻###############((((//*#####(        \n"
    L"       ▼**####*///(((((##☻#################☻#(((((#(((((((((/%/****%%%####((%    \n"
    L"      ((####%%♫*****%%☻((((###############(((/☻//####*////**%%%%♫%%%%%%####(((( \n"
    L"     ((((####%%%%%%%☻%%%*////((((((((((((((//%%%%☻%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%######(((( \n"
    L"    (((((#####%%%☻%%%%%%%***%%%///////////**%%%%%%%%%☻%%%%%%%%%%#########((   ▼  \n "
    L"     ▼   ((###☻###########%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%#############☻##########((((/ ▼        \n"
    L"          (((((((%   ##########################((((    ((((((((                       \n"
    L"                             ╔############╗                                            \n"
    L"                             ║############║                                            \n"
    L"                             ║############║                                            \n"
    L"                             ║############║                                            \n"
    L"                             ╚############╝                                            \n"
    L"░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░\n";


HANDLE handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
int sym[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14 };


while (true) 
{
    wcout << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size(x_mas); i++)
    {
        if (x_mas[i] == L'☻')
        {
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(handle, sym[rand() % size(sym)]);
            wcout << x_mas[i];
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(handle, 7);

        }
        else
        {
            wcout << x_mas[i];
        }

      
    }
    Sleep(delay);
    system("cls");
}




cin.get();
```

}

Answer (score 18):

Минимальная анимация ползучей строки на Python. С прошедшим!

```
from os import system
from time import sleep

string = [
    "░█| ░█  ░███  ░█_░█ ░█_░█ ░█| ░█     ░██  ░█ ░█_░█ ░█          ░█    ░█| ░█ ░█_░█  ░███  ░██_░█      ",
    "░█|_░█ ░█|_░█ ░████ ░████  ░███      ░█|░█░█ ░████  ░█   ░█   ░█      ░███  ░████ ░█|_░█ ░████       ",
    "░█████ ░█████ ░█    ░█      ░█       ░█| ░██ ░█      ░█ ░█░█ ░█        ░█   ░█    ░█████ ░█ ░█       ",
    "░█| ░█ ░█| ░█ ░█    ░█      ░█.......░█|  ░█ ░████    ░██  ░██ ........░█   ░████ ░█| ░█ ░█  ░██     "]


def rotate(l, n):
    return l[n:] + l[:n]


while True:
    system('cls')
    for j in range(len(string)):
        string[j] = rotate(string[j], 1)
    print("\n".join(string))
    sleep(0.01)
```

[image: 1]

Answer (score 17):

немного Нового Года

```
import turtle
import random

def koch_curve(size, n):
    if n == 0:
        turtle.forward(size)
    else:
        koch_curve(size / 3, n - 1)
        turtle.left(60)
        koch_curve(size / 3, n - 1)
        turtle.right(120)
        koch_curve(size / 3, n - 1)
        turtle.left(60)
        koch_curve(size / 3, n - 1)


def draw_koch_snowflake(x, y, size, n):
    turtle.speed(0)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.pendown()
    for i in range(3):
        koch_curve(size, n)
        turtle.right(120)


turtle.hideturtle()

turtle.screensize(800, 600)
scr_size = turtle.screensize()

count = 100
snowflakes = [[random.randint(-0.5 * scr_size[0], +0.5 * scr_size[0]), random.randint(-0.5 * scr_size[1], +0.5 * scr_size[1]), random.randint(10, 50)] for _ in range(count)]

while True:
    turtle.resetscreen()
    turtle.tracer(0, 0)
    scr_size = turtle.screensize()

    for index in range(len(snowflakes)):
        obj = snowflakes[index]
        obj[1] -= random.randint(1, 15)

        if obj[1] < -0.5 * scr_size[0] - 3 * obj[2]:
            snowflakes[index] = [random.randint(-0.5 * scr_size[0], +0.5 * scr_size[0]), random.randint(0.3 * scr_size[1], +0.5 * scr_size[1]), random.randint(10, 50)]

        draw_koch_snowflake(obj[0], obj[1], obj[2], 2)

    turtle.update()
```

Comment: картинку бы еще

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, картинку того, что программа делает?

Comment: @Zhihar ну да, не фотку же деда мороза

Comment: Здорово (еще и python-tk установил!)

Answer (score 16):

```
import random
import time

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, pos, size, arr = None):
        self.x, self.y = pos
        self.size = size
        self.speed = random.uniform(1, 2)
        
        if arr is None:
            self.arr = self.new_arr()
        else:
            self.arr = arr
        
    
    def __str__(self):
        res = ""
        for el in self.arr:
            res += ((bin(el)[3:] + "\n")
                            .replace("1", "#")
                            .replace("0", " "))
        return res
    
    def __or__(self, other):
        arr = []
        for a, b in zip(self.arr, other.arr):
            arr.append(a|b)
        return Ball((self.x, self.y), self.size, arr)
    
    def new_arr(self):
        arr = []
        n = 2 ** self.size[1]
        for i in range(self.size[0]):
            if self.x <= i < self.x + 2:
                arr.append(n + 2**self.y + 2**self.y//2)
            else:
                arr.append(n)
        return arr
    
    def update(self):
        self.x += self.speed
        
        if self.x >= self.size[0]:
            self.x = 0
        self.arr = self.new_arr()
            
        
x_size = 30
y_size = 50

balls = []
for _ in range(10):
    x = random.randrange(x_size - 1)
    y = random.randrange(y_size)
    balls.append(Ball((y, x), (y_size, x_size)))


while True:
    print("\033[2J\033[1;1H")
    res = balls[0]
    for i in range(len(balls)):
        res |= balls[i]
        balls[i].update()
    print(res)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Answer (score 16):

JavaScript веселая консоль поздравляет:

```html
<script>
  var styles = [
    'padding: 1rem; background: red',
    'padding: 1rem; background: transparent',
    'padding: 1rem; background: orange',
    'padding: 1rem; background: gold',
    'padding: 1rem; background: yellowgreen',
    'padding: 1rem; background: skyblue',
    'padding: 1rem; background: steelblue',
    'padding: 1rem; background: transparent',
    'padding: 1rem; background: darkviolet',
    'padding: 1rem; background: red',
    'padding: 1rem; background: orange',
    'padding: 1rem; background: gold',
    'padding: 1rem; background: yellowgreen',
    'padding: 1rem; background: skyblue',
    'padding: 1rem; background: transparent; font-size: 5rem',
  ];

  console.log('%c С %c  %c Н %c О %c В %c Ы %c М %c   %c Г %c О %c Д %c О %c М %c ! %c ',
    styles[0], styles[1], styles[2], styles[3], styles[4],
    styles[5], styles[6], styles[7], styles[8], styles[9],
    styles[10], styles[11], styles[12], styles[13], styles[14]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 13):

```
import time

n = int(input())

for i in range(3, n + 1, 2):
    for j in range(1, i + 1):
        print(" " * (n - j), "0" * (j * 2 - 1))
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

Answer (score 13):

Коллеги, извините за столь краткое поздравление, очень мало времени, но я все же всех Вас поздравляю и хочу, чтобы новый год для всех нас стал по-настоящему новым и продуктивным.
С наступающим!

```
import pygame
import random
pygame.init() 
BLACK = [0, 0, 0]
WHITE = [255, 255, 255]
WIN_SIZE = [400, 400]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(WIN_SIZE)
pygame.display.set_caption("Happy New Year")
snow_list = [] 
for i in range(50):
    x = random.randrange(0, 400)
    y = random.randrange(0, 400)
    snow_list.append([x, y])
 
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            done = True  
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    for i in range(len(snow_list)):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, WHITE, snow_list[i], 2)
        snow_list[i][1] += 1
        if snow_list[i][1] > 400:
            y = random.randrange(-50, -10)
            snow_list[i][1] = y
            x = random.randrange(0, 400)
            snow_list[i][0] = x
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(20)
pygame.quit()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 11):

в довесок к первому :)

```
import random


n = 20

tree = [' ' * (n - i) + '*' * (2 * i - 1) for i in range(n)]

pos = 0
for i in range(n):
    tree[i] = tree[i][:pos + (n - i)] + random.choice(['o', 'x', '@']) + tree[i][pos + (n - i) + 1:]
    pos = (pos + random.randint(3, 7)) % (2 * i - 1)

print(*tree, sep='\n')
```

Comment: Это не анимация.

Comment: @Sevastopol' в задании в текущем его виде требуется сделать именно анимацию. Все вопросы — к Николаю ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 11):

## А вот это... Новогодний чат бот для SE!

```
import datetime
import random
from chatexchange.client import Client

email = "*********"
password = "*********************"
se_chat = Client("stackexchange.com")
se_chat.login(email, password)


def when_ny():
    d = datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1) - datetime.datetime.now()
    room.send_message(' ' + str(d) + ' ')


def happy(who):
    happy_new_year = [' Поздравляю с новым годом! Желаю всего самого лучшего ;) ',
                      ' Поздравляю с новым годом! Отмечаем! ',
                      ' Поздравляю с новым годом! Желаю счастья, любви, здоровья и просто всего доброго!']
    room.send_message(f'@{who} {random.choice(happy_new_year)}')

def fireworks():
    room.send_message('https://www.funimada.com/assets/images/cards/big/ny-75.gif')

def tree(size):
    room.send_message('https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-F8m0sIQpb3c/UM2bTvcgDWI/AAAAAAAAAR4/0prAbw7m1Go/s1600/0_84dd0_4ff0a30_XL.jpg')

commands = {
    'when-ny': when_ny,
    'happy-new-year': happy,
    'fireworks': fireworks,
    'yolka': tree
}


def run(command, *args):
    f = commands.get(command)
    if f:
        try:
            f(*args)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            room.send_message('Ошибка.')
    else:
        room.send_message(f'Нету такой команды, {command}')


def on_event(event, _):
    if event.data['event_type'] == 1:
        msg = event.message.content_source
        if msg.startswith('ny '):
            run(*msg[3:].split(' '))


room = se_chat.get_room('115560')
room.join()
room.send_message(' С Новым Годом! А, еще не Новый Год?')
room.watch_socket(on_event)

while True:
    pass
```

Comment: Не уверен, что это можно считать анимацией

Comment: @andreymal Анимация — это критерий выигрыша. Я за выигрышем не гонюсь.

Answer (score 10):

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var aspectRatio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, aspectRatio, 50, 3000);


renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  alpha: true,
  antialias: true
});



renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x070);
scene.add(light);

var shadowLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 199);
shadowLight.position.set(1500, 1000, 750);
shadowLight.castShadow = true;
shadowLight.shadowMapWidth = 10024;
shadowLight.shadowMapHeight = 10024;
scene.add(shadowLight);

var point = new THREE.PointLight(0xff77ff, 0.5, 300, .25);
point.castShadow = true;

var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 0, 300, .92);
spotLight.position.set(10, 25, 50);

spotLight.shadowMapWidth = 1;
spotLight.shadowMapHeight = 1;
spotLight.onlyShadow = true;
scene.add(spotLight);

camera.position.z = 180;

floor = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(10000, 10000, 64, 64), new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial());
floor.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
floor.receiveShadow = true;
scene.add(floor);

var Tree = function() {
  var mat0 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
color: 0xffff00
  });
  var mat1 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
color: 0x00ff00
  });
  this.mesh = new THREE.Group();

  var mesh0 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(3, 3, 25, 30), mat0);
  mesh0.position.y = 1;
  mesh0.castShadow = true;
  mesh0.receiveShadow = true;
  this.mesh.add(mesh0);

  var geo_igr = new THREE.SphereGeometry(2, 32, 32);
  var mat_igr1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
color: 0xffff00
  });
  var mat_igr2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
color: 0xff33ff
  });
  var mat_igr3 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
color: 0x0066ff
  });
 
 var mat_igr4 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
color: 0x00ff00
  });
  var mat_igr5 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
color: 0xff0006
  });
  var igr1 = new THREE.Mesh(geo_igr, mat_igr1);
  var igr2 = new THREE.Mesh(geo_igr, mat_igr2);
  var igr3 = new THREE.Mesh(geo_igr, mat_igr3);
  var igr4 = new THREE.Mesh(geo_igr, mat_igr4);
  var igr5 = new THREE.Mesh(geo_igr, mat_igr5);
  var igr6 = new THREE.Mesh(geo_igr, mat_igr1);
  var igr7 = new THREE.Mesh(geo_igr, mat_igr2);
  var igr8 = new THREE.Mesh(geo_igr, mat_igr3);
  var igr9 = new THREE.Mesh(geo_igr, mat_igr4);
  var igr10 = new THREE.Mesh(geo_igr, mat_igr5);

  igr1.position.y = 79;
  igr1.position.x = 4;
  igr1.position.z = 8;
  igr1.receiveShadow = true;
  igr2.position.y = 65;
  igr2.position.x = 4;
  igr2.position.z = 10;
  igr2.receiveShadow = true;
  igr3.position.y = 55;
  igr3.position.x = -4;
  igr3.position.z = 12;
  igr3.receiveShadow = true;
  igr4.position.y = 17;
  igr4.position.x = -11;
  igr4.position.z = 20;
  igr4.receiveShadow = true;
  igr5.position.y = 33;
  igr5.position.x = -4;
  igr5.position.z = 20;
  igr5.receiveShadow = true;

  scene.add(igr1);
  scene.add(igr2);
  scene.add(igr3);
  scene.add(igr4);
  scene.add(igr5);

  igr6.position.y = 24;
  igr6.position.x = 5;
  igr6.position.z = 20;
  igr6.receiveShadow = true;
  igr7.position.y = 39;
  igr7.position.x = 13;
  igr7.position.z = 11;
  igr7.castShadow = true;
  igr7.receiveShadow = true;
  igr8.position.y = 22;
  igr8.position.x = 20;
  igr8.position.z = 10;
  igr8.castShadow = true;
  igr8.receiveShadow = true;
  igr9.position.y = 42;
  igr9.position.x = -7;
  igr9.position.z = 15;
  igr9.receiveShadow = true;

  igr10.position.y = 56;
  igr10.position.x = 12;
  igr10.position.z = 5;

  scene.add(igr6);
  scene.add(igr7);
  scene.add(igr8);
  scene.add(igr9);
  scene.add(igr10);

  var mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0, 26, 60, 75), mat1);
  mesh1.position.y = 40;
  mesh1.castShadow = true;
  mesh1.receiveShadow = true;
  this.mesh.add(mesh1);

  var mesh7 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0, 21, 60, 75), mat_igr1);
  mesh7.position.y = 38;
  mesh7.castShadow = true;
  mesh7.receiveShadow = true;
  this.mesh.add(mesh7);

  var mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0, 20, 50, 70), mat1);
  mesh2.position.y = 55;
  mesh2.castShadow = true;
  mesh2.receiveShadow = true;
  this.mesh.add(mesh2);

  var mesh22 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0, 19, 50, 70), mat_igr2);
  mesh22.position.y = 54;
  mesh22.castShadow = true;
  mesh22.receiveShadow = true;
  this.mesh.add(mesh22);

  var mesh3 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0, 15, 40, 70), mat1);
  mesh3.position.y = 67;
  mesh3.castShadow = true;
  mesh3.receiveShadow = true;
  this.mesh.add(mesh3);

  var mesh33 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0, 14, 40, 70), mat_igr3);
  mesh33.position.y = 66;
  mesh33.castShadow = true;
  mesh33.receiveShadow = true;
  this.mesh.add(mesh33);

  var mesh4 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0, 12, 32, 70), mat1);
  mesh4.position.y = 79;
  mesh4.castShadow = true;
  mesh4.receiveShadow = true;
  this.mesh.add(mesh4);

  var mesh44 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0, 11, 32, 70), mat_igr4);
  mesh44.position.y = 78;
  mesh44.castShadow = true;
  mesh44.receiveShadow = true;
  this.mesh.add(mesh44);

  var mesh5 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0, 10, 18, 39), mat1);
  mesh5.position.y = 86;
  mesh5.castShadow = true;
  mesh5.receiveShadow = true;
  this.mesh.add(mesh5);

  var mesh55 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0, 9, 18, 39), mat_igr5);
  mesh55.position.y = 85;
  mesh55.castShadow = true;
  mesh55.receiveShadow = true;
  this.mesh.add(mesh55);


  var mesh55 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0, 9, 18, 39), mat_igr5);
  mesh55.position.y = 85;
  mesh55.castShadow = true;
  mesh55.receiveShadow = true;
  this.mesh.add(mesh55);


  const BoxGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(10, 10, 10);
  const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
color: 0xff0006
  });
  const cube = new THREE.Mesh(BoxGeo, material);
  cube.position.y = 1;
  cube.castShadow = true;
  cube.position.y = 3;
  cube.position.x = -4;
  cube.position.z = 20;
  cube.receiveShadow = true;
  this.mesh.add(cube);

  const BoxGeo1 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(3, 3, 3);
  const material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
color: 0xff33ff
  });
  const cube1 = new THREE.Mesh(BoxGeo1, material1);
  cube1.position.y = 1;
  cube1.castShadow = true;
  cube1.position.y = 1;
  cube1.position.x = -4;
  cube1.position.z = 28;
  cube1.receiveShadow = true;
  this.mesh.add(cube1);

  const BoxGeo2 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(3, 5, 5);
  const material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
color: 0x0066ff
  });
  const cube2 = new THREE.Mesh(BoxGeo2, material2);
  cube2.position.y = 1;
  cube2.castShadow = true;
  cube2.position.y = 1;
  cube2.position.x = 14;
  cube2.position.z = 3;
  cube2.receiveShadow = true;
  this.mesh.add(cube2);

  const BoxGeo3 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(11, 5, 5);
  const material3 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
color: 0xc700e5
  });
  const cube3 = new THREE.Mesh(BoxGeo3, material3);
  cube3.position.y = 1;
  cube3.castShadow = true;
  cube3.position.y = 1;
  cube3.position.x = 14;
  cube3.position.z = -8;
  cube3.receiveShadow = true;
  this.mesh.add(cube3);

  const BoxGeo4 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(11, 12, 23);
  const material4 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
color: 0xfbff00
  });
  const cube4 = new THREE.Mesh(BoxGeo4, material4);
  cube4.position.y = 1;
  cube4.castShadow = true;
  cube4.position.y = 1;
  cube4.position.x = -14;
  cube4.position.z = -2;
  cube4.receiveShadow = true;
  this.mesh.add(cube4);


  const BoxGeo5 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(3, 3, 12);
  const material5 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
color: 0x0221bf
  });
  const cube5 = new THREE.Mesh(BoxGeo5, material5);
  cube5.position.y = 1;
  cube5.castShadow = true;
  cube5.position.y = 1;
  cube5.position.x = -12;
  cube5.position.z = 15;
  cube5.receiveShadow = true;
  this.mesh.add(cube5);

  const BoxGeo6 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(20, 14, 20);
  const material6 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
color: 0x4f038a
  });
  const cube6 = new THREE.Mesh(BoxGeo6, material6);
  cube6.position.y = 1;
  cube6.castShadow = true;
  cube6.position.y = 1;
  cube6.position.x = -12;
  cube6.position.z = -5;
  cube6.receiveShadow = true;
  this.mesh.add(cube6);

};

var trees = [];
var tree = new Tree();
scene.add(tree.mesh);

var snowflakeCount = 40000;
var pMaterial = new THREE.PointCloudMaterial({
  color: 0xFFFFFF,
  size: 1.1,
  blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
  depthTest: false,
  transparent: true
});
var snowflake = new THREE.Geometry;

for (var i = 0; i < snowflakeCount; i++) {
  var pX = Math.random() * 11000 - (Math.random() * 1677),
pY = Math.random() * 11000 - (Math.random() * 1677),
pZ = Math.random() * 11000 - (Math.random() * 1677),
particle = new THREE.Vector3(pX, pY, pZ);
  particle.velocity = {};
  particle.velocity.y = -3;
  snowflake.vertices.push(particle);
}

var snowflakeystem = new THREE.PointCloud(snowflake, pMaterial);
snowflakeystem.position.y = 20;
scene.add(snowflakeystem);

var snow = function() {
  var pCount = snowflakeCount;
  while (pCount--) {
var particle = snowflake.vertices[pCount];
if (particle.y < -200) {
  particle.y = 200;
  particle.velocity.y = -0.2;
}
particle.velocity.y -= Math.random() * .003;
particle.y += particle.velocity.y;
  }
  snowflake.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
};

var step = 0;

function render() {

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

  camera.position.y = 70 + Math.sin((step / 1000) * Math.PI * 2) * -10;
  camera.position.x = Math.sin((step / 400) * Math.PI * 2) * 177;
  camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 8, -30));
  camera.rotation.z = Math.sin((step / 400) * Math.PI * 2) * Math.PI / 80;
  point.intensity = 5 + Math.sin((step / 400) * Math.PI * 2) / 87;
  shadowLight.intensity = 1;
  shadowLight.shadowDarkness = 0.5;
  snow();

  step++;
  step = step % 1200;
}
render();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #000;
}

canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r70/three.min.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 9):

Code-golfed Yolka!!! ;D

```
from random import*;print(''.join(f'{" "*(10-i)}/{"".join(choices("0*-o.%@ ",k=i*2))}\ \n'for i in range(10)))
```

Comment: писать в одну строку с помощью `;` надо лишь внутри функции чтобы сэкономить байт на обязательном проблем.

Comment: @Danis На сколько я зная код гольф это oneliner'ы

Comment: нет, писать в одну строку не обязательно. Можно сэкономить много байтов есть из `random` импортировать все с помощью `*`

Comment: @Danis Точно я туплю. ;)

Answer (score 9):

Uno, uno... Dos, dos... xD

(подстраивается под размер окна)

```js
"use strict";

let canvas;
// canvas.ctx, canvas.size (квадрат)

let _c, santa, ANIMATE;

/*****/

(function _namespace() {
  // canvas mini-lib
  
  _c /* GLOBAL */ = function (ctx) {
    return new ContextWrap(ctx);
  };

  _c.rotateMatrix = function (matrix, centerPoints, angle) {
    if (angle === 0) return matrix;

    var cx = centerPoints[0];
    var cy = centerPoints[1];
    var sin = Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180);
    var cos = Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180);

    for (var i = 0, len = matrix.length; i < len; i++) {
      var px = matrix[i][0];
      var py = matrix[i][1];

      matrix[i][0] = cos * (px - cx) - sin * (py - cy) + cx;
      matrix[i][1] = sin * (px - cx) + cos * (py - cy) + cy;
    }

    return matrix;
  };

  _c.rotatePoint = function (point, center, angle) {
    if (angle === 0) return point;

    var cx = center[0];
    var cy = center[1];
    var px = point[0];
    var py = point[1];

    var sin = Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180);
    var cos = Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180);

    return [
      cos * (px - cx) - sin * (py - cy) + cx,
      sin * (px - cx) + cos * (py - cy) + cy
    ];
  };

  function ContextWrap(ctx) {
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    this.ctx = ctx;
  }


  CreatePrototype.call(ContextWrap.prototype);

  /***/

  function CreatePrototype() {
    this.clear = function () {
      this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.ctx.canvas.width, this.ctx.canvas.height);
      return this;
    };

    this.fillStyle = function (color) {
      this.ctx.fillStyle = color;
      return this;
    };

    this.path = function (matrix) {
      var ctx = this.ctx;

      ctx.beginPath();
      for (var i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        ctx.lineTo(matrix[i][0], matrix[i][1]);
      }
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fill();

      return this;
    };

    this.arc = function (cx, cy, r, start, end) {
      var ctx = this.ctx;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(cx, cy, r, start || 0, end || 2 * Math.PI);
      ctx.fill();

      return this;
    };

    this.ellipse = function (cx, cy, rx, ry, rotate, start, end) {
      var ctx = this.ctx;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.ellipse(cx, cy, rx, ry, rotate || 0, start || 0, end || 2 * Math.PI);
      ctx.fill();

      return this;
    };
  };

})();


/*****/

canvas /* GLOBAL */ = (function () {

  let cnv = document.querySelector("#scene");
  let ctx = cnv.getContext("2d");
  let size = cnv.width = cnv.height = Math.min(innerWidth, innerHeight);

  let _data_ = { ctx, size };


  let timer = null;

  addEventListener("resize", function () {
    clearTimeout(timer);

    timer = setTimeout(function () {
      _data_.size = cnv.width = cnv.height = Math.min(innerWidth, innerHeight);
    }, 500);
  });


  return _data_;
})();


/*****/

function DRAW() {
  _c(canvas.ctx).clear();

  let _tmp = [santa /* , snow_maiden */];

  _tmp.forEach(char => {
    char.init_skelet(canvas);

    Object.values(char.render)
      .sort((a, b) => a.z_index - b.z_index)
      .forEach(function (obj) {
        char[obj.call](canvas, obj);
      });
  });
};


/*****/

santa = {};

santa.position = {
  // Относительные ключевые точки, домножаются на масштаб и рисуются.
  
  head: {
    dx: 0,
    dy: 0,
    r: 0.15,
  },

  body: {
    bot_x: 0.5,
    bot_y: 0.7,

    rotate: 0,
  },

  leg1: {
    dx: 1, // 0 → 1
  },

  leg2: {    
    dx: 1, // 0 → 1
  },
};

santa.skelet = null;

santa.render = {

  head: {
    z_index: 100,
    fill: "#ebba9a",
    call: "head",
  },

  body: {
    z_index: 40,
    fill: "#c11",
    call: "body",
  },

  hand: {
    z_index: 50,
    fill: "#c11",
    call: "hand",
  },

  foot: {
    z_index: 30,
    fill: "#c11",
    call: "foot",
  },

};

santa.init_skelet = function (cnv) {

  let size = cnv.size;
  let pos = santa.position;
  let skel = santa.skelet = {};


  /*** BODY */

  let b = pos.body;
  let neck_x = b.bot_x * size;
  let neck_y = b.bot_y * size - 0.2 * size;

  skel.body = _c.rotateMatrix(
    [
      [b.bot_x * size - 0.1 * size, b.bot_y * size],
      [neck_x - 0.1 * size, neck_y],
      [neck_x + 0.1 * size, neck_y],
      [b.bot_x * size + 0.1 * size, b.bot_y * size],
    ],
    [b.bot_x * size, b.bot_y * size],
    b.rotate
  );


  /*** HEAD */
  let h = pos.head;

  let head_center = _c.rotatePoint(
    [neck_x, neck_y - h.r * size],
    [b.bot_x * size, b.bot_y * size],
    b.rotate
  );

  skel.head = {
    cx: head_center[0],
    cy: head_center[1],
    r: h.r * size,
  };

  /*** EYES */
  skel.eyes = {
    "1": {
      cx: skel.head.cx - 0.04 * size,
      cy: skel.head.cy,
      rx: size * h.r * 0.25,
      ry: size * h.r * 0.35,
    },
    "2": {
      cx: skel.head.cx + 0.04 * size,
      cy: skel.head.cy,
      rx: size * h.r * 0.25,
      ry: size * h.r * 0.35,
    }
  };

  /*** NOSE */
  skel.nose = {
    cx: skel.head.cx,
    cy: skel.head.cy + 0.06 * size,
    rx: size * h.r * 0.4,
    ry: size * h.r * 0.25,
  };

  /*** BEARD */
  let hx = skel.head.cx;
  let hy = skel.head.cy;

  skel.beard = [
    [hx - size * h.r, hy - 0.06 * size],
    [hx - size * h.r * 0.8, hy],
    [hx, hy + 0.08 * size],
    [hx + size * h.r * 0.8, hy],
    [hx + size * h.r, hy - 0.06 * size],

    [hx + size * h.r, hy + 0.05 * size],
    [hx + size * h.r * 0.8, hy + 0.15 * size],
    [hx, hy + 0.25 * size],
    [hx - size * h.r * 0.8, hy + 0.15 * size],
    [hx - size * h.r, hy + 0.05 * size],
  ];

  /*** HAT_TOP */
  skel.hat_top = {
    cx: hx,
    cy: hy - 0.2 * size,
    r: size * h.r * 0.4
  };

  /*** HAT */
  skel.hat = [    
    [hx - size * h.r, hy - 0.05 * size],
    [hx - size * h.r, hy - 0.07 * size],
    [hx - size * h.r * 0.6, hy - 0.15 * size],
    [hx, hy - 0.2 * size],
    [hx + size * h.r * 0.6, hy - 0.15 * size],
    [hx + size * h.r, hy - 0.07 * size],
    [hx + size * h.r, hy - 0.05 * size],
    
    [hx + size * h.r * 0.6, hy - 0.06 * size],
    [hx - size * h.r * 0.6, hy - 0.06 * size],
  ];



  /***/

  /*** HANDS */
  //  shoulder
  let sh1_x = skel.body[1][0];
  let sh1_y = skel.body[1][1];

  skel.hand1 = [
    [sh1_x - size * 0.042, sh1_y - size * 0.08],
    [sh1_x, sh1_y],
    [sh1_x - size * 0.03, sh1_y + size * 0.05],
    [sh1_x, sh1_y + size * 0.12],
    [sh1_x - size * 0.03, sh1_y + size * 0.18],
    [sh1_x - size * 0.09, sh1_y + size * 0.05],    
  ];

  let sh2_x = skel.body[2][0];
  let sh2_y = skel.body[2][1];

  skel.hand2 = [
    [sh2_x + size * 0.042, sh2_y - size * 0.08],
    [sh2_x, sh2_y],
    [sh2_x + size * 0.03, sh2_y + size * 0.05],
    [sh2_x, sh2_y + size * 0.12],
    [sh2_x + size * 0.03, sh2_y + size * 0.18],
    [sh2_x + size * 0.09, sh2_y + size * 0.05],    
  ];

  /*** FEET */
  let leg1_dx = pos.leg1.dx * 0.05;
  let f1_x = skel.body[0][0];
  let f1_y = skel.body[0][1];

  skel.foot1 = [
    [f1_x, f1_y],
    [f1_x + size * 0.08, f1_y],
    [f1_x + size * 0.09 - size * leg1_dx, f1_y + size * 0.1],
    [f1_x + size * 0.1, f1_y + size * 0.24],
    [f1_x - size * 0.05, f1_y + size * 0.24],
    [f1_x - size * leg1_dx, f1_y + size * 0.1],
  ];

  let leg2_dx = pos.leg2.dx * 0.05;
  let f2_x = skel.body[3][0];
  let f2_y = skel.body[3][1];

  skel.foot2 = [
    [f2_x, f2_y],
    [f2_x - size * 0.08, f2_y],
    [f2_x - size * 0.09 + size * leg2_dx, f2_y + size * 0.1],
    [f2_x - size * 0.1, f2_y + size * 0.24],
    [f2_x + size * 0.05, f2_y + size * 0.24],
    [f2_x + size * leg2_dx, f2_y + size * 0.1],
  ];
};


/*****/
santa.body = function (cnv, obj) {
  _c(cnv.ctx)
    .fillStyle(obj.fill)
    .path(santa.skelet.body);
};

santa.head = function (cnv, obj) {
  let skel = santa.skelet;
  let { cx, cy, r } = skel.head;

  _c(cnv.ctx)
    .fillStyle(obj.fill)
    .arc(cx, cy, r);

  santa.beard(cnv);
  santa.eyes(cnv);
  santa.nose(cnv);
  santa.hat(cnv);
};

santa.beard = function (cnv) {
  _c(cnv.ctx)
    .fillStyle("#fff")
    .path(santa.skelet.beard);
};

santa.eyes = function (cnv) {
  let e = santa.skelet.eyes;

  _c(cnv.ctx)
    .fillStyle("#123")
    .ellipse(e[1].cx, e[1].cy, e[1].rx, e[1].ry)
    .ellipse(e[2].cx, e[2].cy, e[2].rx, e[2].ry);
};

santa.nose = function (cnv) {
  let n = santa.skelet.nose;

  _c(cnv.ctx)
    .fillStyle("#a00")
    .ellipse(n.cx, n.cy, n.rx, n.ry);
};

santa.hat = function (cnv) {
  let t = santa.skelet.hat_top;

  _c(cnv.ctx)
    .fillStyle("#fff")
    .arc(t.cx, t.cy, t.r)

    .fillStyle("#c11")
    .path(santa.skelet.hat);
};

//...

santa.hand = function (cnv) {

  _c(cnv.ctx)
    .fillStyle("#c11")
    .path(santa.skelet.hand1)
    .path(santa.skelet.hand2);
};

santa.foot = function (cnv) {
  _c(cnv.ctx)
    .fillStyle("#c11")
    .path(santa.skelet.foot1)
    .path(santa.skelet.foot2);
};


/*****/
ANIMATE /* GLOBAL */ = {

  // 1. ANIMATE.add(obj) — заворачивает obj в функию,
  // 2. Добавляет её в хранилище _fn_storage,
  // 3. На каждом animationFrame оттуда циклом вызываются все функции
  // 4. На основе данных из obj, каждая функция меняет анимируемые значения
  //    (сколько необходимо за один кадр)
    
  _unique_key: 0,
  _fn_storage: {},

  add: function (obj) {    
    this._fn_storage[obj._self = this._unique_key++] = this._get_closure_fn(obj);

    return this;
  },

  _get_closure_fn: function (obj) {
    /* obj = { 
         root: santa.position.hand,
         prop: "rotate",
         chain: [
           {to: -90, ms: 1000},
           {sleep: 1000, callback: fn},
           {to: 70, ms: 1000, callback: fn},
         ],
       } */

    /***/

    let i = 0, curr = obj.chain[i];

    let change_per_ms; // {Number} : изменение анимируемого значения за 1 мс.
    let reached_end; // {Function → return Boolean}

    _update_params();

    return function _animate(dt) {
      /*** dt {Number} : Время, прошедшее после предыдущего вызова animationFrame ***/

      if (curr._sleeping) return;
      /*** Будет прерываться, пока не пройдет curr.sleep миллисекунд ***/

      if (curr.sleep) {
        curr._sleeping = true;

        setTimeout(
          function () {
            curr._sleeping = false;
            next();
          },
          curr.sleep
        );

        return;
      }

      let newVal = obj.root[obj.prop] + change_per_ms * dt;
      if (reached_end(newVal)) {
        obj.root[obj.prop] = curr.to;
        next();
        return;
      }

      obj.root[obj.prop] = newVal;

      /***/
      function next() {
        if (curr.callback) curr.callback(obj);

        i = typeof curr.goto == "number" ? curr.goto : i + 1;

        curr = obj.chain[i];
        if (!curr) return ANIMATE.remove(obj);

        _update_params();
      }
    }

    /***/
    function _update_params() {
      if (curr.sleep) return;

      let from = curr.from || obj.root[obj.prop];

      change_per_ms = (curr.to - from) / curr.ms;
      reached_end = (from > curr.to) ?
        (newVal) => newVal <= curr.to :
        (newVal) => newVal >= curr.to;
    }
  },

  remove: function (obj) {
    delete this._fn_storage[obj._self];
  },
};


/*****/

ANIMATE.add({
  root: santa.position.leg1,
  prop: "dx",
  chain: [
    { to: -0.2, ms: 138 },
    { to: 1, ms: 276, goto: 0 },
  ],
}).add({
  root: santa.position.leg2,
  prop: "dx",
  chain: [
    { to: -0.2, ms: 138 },
    { to: 1, ms: 276, goto: 0 },
  ],
});

ANIMATE.start = function () {
  let k = 0, last_call = null;

  let loop = (time) => {
    if (k++ % 2) return requestAnimationFrame(loop); // 30 fps

    let dt = time - last_call;

    for (let fn in this._fn_storage) {
      this._fn_storage[fn](dt);
    }

    DRAW();

    last_call = time;

    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  };

  requestAnimationFrame(function (init_time) {
    last_call = init_time;
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  });
};

ANIMATE.start();
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0 } canvas { background-color: #ddd }
```

```html
<canvas id="scene"></canvas>
```

Comment: Главное не ddos, ddos! ;)

Comment: [Вариант CSS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1230794/377637)

Answer (score 8):

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/sparklingman/pen/MWjKmJB)

```js
var ny, cloud, land, spruce, branches, snow, smile, garland;
ny = document.querySelector("#ny");
cloud = document.createElement("div");
land = document.createElement("div");
spruce = document.createElement("div");
branches = document.createElement("div");
mountain = document.createElement("div");
garland = document.createElement("div");
cloud.setAttribute("id", "cloud");
ny.appendChild(cloud);
smile = document.createElement("span");
smile.setAttribute("class", "smile");
smile.innerHTML = "&#65078;";
ny.append(smile);
snow = document.createElement("div");
cloud.appendChild(snow);
spruce.setAttribute("id", "spruce");
ny.appendChild(spruce);
branches.setAttribute("id", "branches");
spruce.appendChild(branches);
garland.setAttribute("id", "garland");
branches.appendChild(garland);
land.setAttribute("id", "land");
document.body.appendChild(land);

function snowList() {
  var fr = new DocumentFragment();
  for (let i = 1; i <= 14; i++) {
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.innerHTML = "&#10052;";
    fr.append(span);
  }
  return fr;
}

snow.append(snowList());
```

```css
*,
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  align-items: end;
  background: linear-gradient(MediumBlue, dodgerblue, aliceBlue);
  display: flex;
  font-size: 3vmin;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
}

#ny {
  bottom: 2vmin;
  display: flex;
  height: 70vmin;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 40vmin;
  z-index: 10;
}

#cloud {
  background: AliceBlue;
  border-radius: 6vmin;
  height: 12vmin;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 34vmin;
  z-index: 10;
}

#cloud::after {
  animation: cloudCircle 1.3s ease-in-out infinite;
  background: AliceBlue;
  border-radius: 100%;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 10vmin;
  position: absolute;
  top: -6vmin;
  left: 5vmin;
  width: 10vmin;
}

#cloud::before {
  animation: cloudCircle 1.3s 0.3s ease-in infinite;
  background: AliceBlue;
  border-radius: 100%;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 17vmin;
  position: absolute;
  top: -9vmin;
  left: 12vmin;
  width: 17vmin;
}

.smile {
  left: 50%;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0 0 0 -4.5vmin;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 9vmin;
  width: 10vmin;
  z-index: 10;
}

.smile::after {
  content: "\FE35";
  left: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: -6vmin;
}

.smile::before {
  content: "\FE35";
  line-height: 1;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: -6vmin;
}

#land {
  background: white;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 8vmin;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

#spruce {
  border-color: brown transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 2.5vmin 45vmin;
  bottom: 2vmin;
  left: 50%;
  height: 0px;
  margin: 0 0 0 -2.5vmin;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-radius: 5vmin;
}

#spruce::after {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5vmin;
  bottom: -46vmin;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  height: 5vmin;
  position: absolute;
  right: -4vmin;
  width: 5vmin;
}

#spruce::before {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  bottom: -45vmin;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  height: 3vmin;
  left: -3vmin;
  position: absolute;
  width: 3vmin;
}

#branches {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 15vmin;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 15vmin;
  border-color: green transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 20vmin 20vmin;
  bottom: -38vmin;
  height: 0;
  left: -20vmin;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
}

#branches::after {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 10vmin;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 10vmin;
  border-color: green transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 14vmin 14vmin;
  bottom: -6vmin;
  content: "";
  height: 0px;
  left: -14vmin;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
}

#branches::before {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 10vmin;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 10vmin;
  border-color: green transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 10vmin 14vmin;
  bottom: 4vmin;
  content: "";
  height: 0px;
  left: -10vmin;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
}

#garland {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10vmin 10vmin;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10vmin 10vmin;
  border-color: transparent transparent khaki transparent;
  border-style: dotted;
  border-width: 0.7vmin;
  height: 15vmin;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0 0 0 -9vmin;
  position: absolute;
  top: -14vmin;
  width: 17vmin;
  z-index: 10;
}

#garland::after {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10vmin 10vmin;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10vmin 10vmin;
  border-color: transparent transparent lightblue transparent;
  border-style: dotted;
  border-width: 0.7vmin;
  content: "";
  height: 10vmin;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0 0 0 -6vmin;
  position: absolute;
  top: -8vmin;
  width: 10vmin;
  z-index: 10;
}

#garland::before {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30vmin 30vmin;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30vmin 30vmin;
  border-color: transparent transparent orange transparent;
  border-style: dotted;
  border-width: 0.7vmin;
  content: "";
  height: 14vmin;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0 0 0 -15vmin;
  position: absolute;
  top: 14vmin;
  width: 28vmin;
  z-index: 10;
}

#cloud span {
  animation: fall 6s 0s linear infinite;
  color: AliceBlue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 14vmin;
  top: 0;
}

#cloud span:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0;
  left: 10vmin;
  top: 10vmin;
}

#cloud span:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
  left: 10vmin;
  top: 0;
}

#cloud span:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
  left: 8vmin;
  top: 0;
}

#cloud span:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
  font-size: 60%;
  left: 25vmin;
  top: 8vmin;
}

#cloud span:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 5.5s;
  font-size: 60%;
  left: 8vmin;
  top: 3vmin;
}

#cloud span:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  left: 2vmin;
  top: 2vmin;
}

#cloud span:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: 2.8s;
  left: 25vmin;
  top: -5vmin;
}

#cloud span:nth-child(8) {
  animation-delay: 4.5s;
  font-size: 60%;
  left: 14vmin;
  top: 0;
}

#cloud span:nth-child(9) {
  animation-delay: 2.5s;
  left: 8vmin;
  top: 8vmin;
}

#cloud span:nth-child(10) {
  animation-delay: 3.5s;
  font-size: 60%;
  left: 22vmin;
  top: 10vmin;
}

#cloud span:nth-child(11) {
  animation-delay: 2.2s;
  left: 20vmin;
  top: -3vmin;
}

#cloud span:nth-child(12) {
  animation-delay: 1.2s;
  font-size: 50%;
  left: 5vmin;
  top: 8vmin;
}

#cloud span:nth-child(13) {
  animation-delay: 1.2s;
  left: 20vmin;
  top: 2vmin;
}

#cloud span:nth-child(14) {
  animation-delay: 2.9s;
  font-size: 60%;
  left: 15vmin;
  top: 6vmin;
}

@keyframes fall {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(10vmin, 30vmin) rotate(90deg);
  }
  95% {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 60vmin) rotate(360deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes cloudCircle {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="ny"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Классная елочка на C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string multiStr(string str, int num)
{
    string res;
    int i;
    
    for (i=0;i<num;i++) {
        res = res + str;
    }
    
    return res;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    
    cout << "It is a C++ program! Copyrigth (c) Foton-PC 2021.\n\nHappy Hew Year!\n\n" << endl;
    
    int i;
    int i2;
    int lines;
    
    cout << "Please, entry number _";
    cin >> lines;
    
    for (i2=1;i2<lines+1;i2++) 
    {
        
    for (i=1;i<i2+1;i++) 
    {
    cout << multiStr("L",i) << endl;
    }
    
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```