# Создание крестика в CSS

Tags: html, css

Мне нужно воссоздать крестик ( вот такой [image: крестик] ) при помощи css

Comment: Мы готовы рассмотреть ваши попытки и подсказать.

Comment: 1. Заинтайнить svg в background.
2. Сделать 2 пересекающихся наклонных градиента, но углы получатся острыми. Можно дорезать через clip-path или ещё 2 или 4 градиента.
3. Сделать горизонтальный и вертикальный градиенты и повернуть с помощью transform.
4. Вместо градиентов использовать 2 псевдоэлемента.
5. Если фон однотонный, закрашивать не линии, а треугольники. Впрочем, я не вижу причин так делать.

Comment: Ну и зачем минусовать нормальный вопрос?

Comment: Используй  юникод  шрифты ```&times;```

Comment: @Qwertiy: минусуют за лень и невежество. Не будет приложен код и/или описана конкретная проблема, то я тоже присоединюсь к минусующим.

Comment: @UModeL, всё вполне конкретно описано. Код не нужен.

Comment: @Qwertiy "вот такой крестик" - вопрос-картинка, однако

Comment: @andreymal, _"крестик"_ написано вполне текстом. И вопросы-картинки вообще-то не запрещены.

Comment: @Qwertiy а вот какой «такой» крестик — не написано. Просто крестик на CSS можно и так сделать `::before { content: '×'; }` — но вряд ли автор имел в виду именно это

Comment: @Sevastopol' [тык раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/1105132/6), [тык два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/1113095/1), ну и заодно [тык три](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1226672)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Сложный вопрос ⇒ непростой ответ:

```css
div {cursor: pointer; position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 10px;}
div:before, div:after {content: ""; position: absolute; width: 24px; height: 4px; background: gray;}
div:before {transform: rotate(45deg);}
div:after {transform: rotate(-45deg);}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Через `background` и `linear-gradient`

```css
.close {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  --weight: 3px;
  --aa: 1px; /* anti-aliasing */
  --color: red;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(45deg, transparent calc(50% - var(--weight) - var(--aa)), var(--color) calc(50% - var(--weight)), var(--color) calc(50% + var(--weight)), transparent calc(50% + var(--weight) + var(--aa))),
    linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent calc(50% - var(--weight) - var(--aa)), var(--color) calc(50% - var(--weight)), var(--color) calc(50% + var(--weight)), transparent calc(50% + var(--weight) + var(--aa)));
}
```

```html
<div class="close"></div>
```

Comment: @Sevastopol', прошу прощения, спасибо))

Answer (score 4):

Можно я тоже? )

```css
.close {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  background-color: red;
  clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 0% 20%, 30% 50%, 0% 80%, 20% 100%, 50% 70%, 80% 100%, 100% 80%, 70% 50%, 100% 20%, 80% 0%, 50% 30%);
}
```

```html
<div class="close"></div>
```

Comment: хочеться рыдать...где cursor:pointer? (PS: Ответ интересный ;)

Comment: @GGO блин, оказывается в комментах предлагали такое решение (